# Stable IDs and ViewTypes in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development and I am learning about stable IDs. I can understand how it works and enables lots of optimisations. What I need to know is,

Can we have same id for different view types or the ID should be unique across all the view types? For Example, let us assume I have 10 items in my adapter with 2 View types. Say, 5 items of each view types. Now, can I have ID from 1 to 5 in each view type or I should have unique ID of 1 to 10 for all 10 items in my adapter?

Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need unique ID for every item in the adapter. I think it's not even possible to use duplicates because adapter will simply crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item in your adapter needs to have a unique `Id`. In your case, from 1 to 10.

You can see that in the [RecyclerView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java#4162).